# Validates association in child class of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-associations, activemodel

I am facing strange issue in validating presence of association in a derived class.

```
Class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :things

end

Class SubContact < Contact

# validates_presence_of :things
  validate :must_have_things

  def must_have_things
    if things.blank?
      errors.add("Must select things")
    end
  end

end
```

In `SubContact` class, I am trying to validate presence of things but nothing is working. I have tried both custom and built in validators
How can I achieve this?

Comment: @alexanderbird in question OP never mentioned STI, so I dont think the link is usefull

Comment: Isn't the OP's sample code showing STI? I guess if there is no type column in the contacts table then it isn't STI...

Comment: yes we don't have any type column.

Comment: I've deleted the link to avoid confusing people - you're right, it's not related.

Answer (score 3):

`add` needs an attribute. Try using:

```
errors.add(:base, "Must not be blank")
```

In this case, it is the base class but it can be any other attribute too. Mention an attribute name of the SubContract class or `:base`.

Comment: No need to return true or false as we are adding error but even if we do it still doesn't work.

Comment: No @mhaseeb this thing isn't working for inherited resources.